# How to use resources for globalization in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, resources, globalization

I have an application which will be used by multiple companies.So my views/pages are being accessed by all these companies and each company will have their respective content... for e.g. there are 5 titles so each company will have their own titles on each page. So , I am using **different resource** files for each company and changing the titles.

If I only use one resource file everything works fine but I would like to have multiple resource files under **App_GlobalResources** directory where my names are `Resource1.resx, Resource1.comp1.resx, Resource1.comp2.resx` something similar but this **does not work**.

But it **works** when I am using language specific notations like `Resource1.en.resx,Resource1.es.resx` etc. But I really don't want to use that way...Can anyone help me getting to use these resource files to change my content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For globalization - check this [guide](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx).

But Your problem is that You want to use resources not only for globalization but changing content according to which company accesses it. Wrong tool for the job. That should be done otherwise.

Comment: so what would be the best way you suggest to accomplish something like this...thanks.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing context. Something like storing all titles into database, knowing 'current company' and passing correct `Title` to view model might work.